# Как решать задачи, описанные в основной части?

Tags: java, математика

Прохожу курс по java на [stepik](https://stepik.org/lesson/605578/step/7?unit=600689)
Попалась такая задача:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как она, и подобные ей задачи, решаются? Прошу объяснить максимально простыми словами. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: У вас есть точка с координатами (x,y). Математически — когда она принадлежит закрашенной области?

Comment: Когда она в ней находится. Но как это максимально эффективно закодить? Мне не очень понятно как в коде обозначить закрашенную зону.

Comment: Если прямая описывается  уравнением `y=2*x`, то какие y будут выше неё при данном `x`? Те, что больше `2*x`, т.е. `if (y>2*x)...`

Comment: Координаты точек на линии известны - дана формула. Если взять любую точку на оси Х, то точки (x, y) с каким значением Y лежат в закрашенной области?

Comment: **Почему** точка (1,3) в закрашенной зоне, а (3,1) — в незакрашенной? Какое неравенство определяет множество точек в закрашенной зоне? Как намек: если бы это была горизонтальная линия y = 0, то какие точки были бы в закрашенной зоне? С какими ординатами?

Answer (score 0):

Все просто. Смотрите у вас есть равенство y=f(x), где f(x) это некая функция, зависящая от х.  Если посмотреть на 2-х мерное пространство... он будет разделено на 2 части вашей функцией. И все y равные значению f(x) соответственно являются точками функции и лежат на линии f(x). Тогда, если вам окрасили часть пространства выше f(x), то логично предположить, что y>f(x), а если мы говорим о части, что ниже графика y=f(x), то соответственно это y<f(x).